# What can be the advantages of using "normal" trigger mode in an oscilloscope?

Tags: oscilloscope

I'm not an advanced scope user and almost all the time I use it in Auto trigger mode. What I know about the normal mode is that if the trigger level is outside of the signal range the signal on the screen disappears(analog scope) or freezes(DSO).

But in what situations would normal mode be used in practice?

Comment: It may be important for you to know if the signal is no longer reaching the trigger threshold.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question asks for a list.  There are hundreds of answers.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson - it is also useful to find if a threshold is being *exceeded* when it should not be.

Comment: It's useful when the thing you want to observe happens infrequently enough that autotrigger would go into automode and fill up the screen with things you aren't interested in.

Answer (score 2):

The 'normal' mode keeps the last triggered picture.
In 'auto' mode the information disappears.

Most events I study are single events or burst events. (e.g. 4 writes on an SPI interface). I use 'normal' because I can see what happened many seconds ago.
In fact it is this capability which make a digital scope superior to an analogue one. (Except the very expensive ones which had a phosphor memory).

Comment: You could just hit STOP as well.  Further, analog scopes have both trigger modes, and both have their uses.